# Representing multiple attributes of single point feature with icons?

Tags: point, fields-attributes, representation

I always wondered if there's a way to represent using an array of various icons multiple attributes of a single layer containing point features.  For example, think about a point feature with these two attributes:

- Primary activity:  1, 2, 3
- Secondary activity: 1, 2, 3

A feature could have values for these attributes like (1,1) or (2,1) the values are qualitative discrete like data, not continuous numerical, let's say something like: 1 commerce, 2 finance, 3 health services.

I would like to represent the point with all the combination of activities in a way their activities icons arrange around or aside the point, not by overlaying separate layers with representation for each one of the activity attributes, because the overlaid icons would not be legible.

Values for attributes can't be represent by color-form combinations, they should be represented with specific icons for the activity.

Comment: Is it limited to just two columns or could you have more so (1,4,2) etc

Comment: There are several ways of doing this. Where exactly are you stuck? What have you tried?

Comment: What software & version are you using?

Comment: You should probably include a diagram to show what you are after.  I'll give you some extra reputation (+1) because you may not have enough to do this yet.  Also, I seem to remember reading somewhere (but cannot find a link) that GIS Stack Exchange is conducted in English so you may want to delete the Spanish.  However, I may be mistaken on that so perhaps wait for someone else to confirm before you do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Symbolize by Unique Values many Fields](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000003m000000)

Comment: This is a great answer for ArcGIS 10.0+ users.